# Connection SDE and PDE problem with time dependent probability measure

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

I am just working my way through a talk from an Italian researcher and I don´t get one of his points. Let´s look at these two slides.

[image]
 [image]

I don´t understand why he says on slide 2 that $u_t$ is a time dependent probability measure i.e density. Because in my opinion if $u_t$ were a probability density then the total derivate can´t include a source term i.e

$$ \frac{d u}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac
{1}{2} \triangle u $$

Otherwise $\int_{\Omega} u(t,x)dx = 1$ is not fulfilled. But as I assume the researcher is right there must be any mistake in my considerations. Can someone help?

Comment: But time dependent probability measure is also wrong isn´t it?

Comment: Because I think it is not normalized and thus not a probability measure. Am I wrong?

Comment: Because $u(t,x)$ fulfills the PDE with source term and as $u(t,x)$ stands for the particle density so if we integrate over the whole space the result does not stay constant. Without source term we would always have N for the integral and could normalize by N. I know I am wrong but I do not see the mistake. Could you enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

By time dependent density he just means the density u(t,x) is the probability to start from a particular initial point (t0, x0) and to arrive later at the ('uncertain') state (t,x). I don't know the exact context of the physical problem from your slides, but I don't see anything wrong in it. Your statement: $ \int_\Omega{u(t,x)dx}=1$ is correct but your statement for total derivate: $$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}-\frac{1}{2}\delta u$$ seems wrong and is different than in the slide. The PDE from your slide is a Fisher-KPP type of PDE:
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\Delta u+\lambda u$$

Cheers.